# list ALL library name in SAS LIBRARIES

Tags: sas

I would like to search a sas data sets with name include "Loan".

If i know the specific library i can do it by `proc datasets`

```
proc datasets
    library = work
    memtype = data;
    contents
        data = _all_ (keep = libname memname name)
        out = work.table_name;
quit;
run;
```

(afterward i will select those memname contains "loan" using `index` function)

I would like to change the line `library = work` to `library = _all_`
While it file to access the library information. Is there any alternative way to achieve the task?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the SASHELP.VTABLE view.  It lists all tables in all libraries

```
proc sql noprint;
   create table search as
      select * from sashelp.vtable
         where upcase(memname) like '%LOAN%';
quit;
```

or

```
data search;
   set sashelp.vtable;
   if index(upcase(memname),'LOAN');
run;
```

Comment: i am sorry maybe my question is a bit miss-leading. I would like to access all library name. What you are doing is only concern library sashelp. i may have other library like work, libA, libB etc

Comment: Please try the code.  SASHELP.VTABLE is a table that lists all tables in all libraries.

Answer (score 3):

You could use "Dictionary" tables of SAS for this purpuse, you can search datasets name, column name etc

```
proc sql;
   create table mytable as
      select * from sashelp.vtable
      where upcase(memname) like '%LOAN%';
quit;
```

For example:-

```
 VCATALG Provides information about SAS catalogs.
 VCOLUMN Provides information about column in tables.
 VEXTFL Provides information related to external files.
 FORMATS Provides information related to defined formats and informats.
 VINDEX Provides information related to defined indexes.
 VMACRO Provides information related to any defined macros.
 VOPTION Provides information related to SAS system options.
 VTABLE Provides information related to currently defined tables.
 VTITLE Provides information related to currently defined titles and footnotes.
 VVIEW Provides information related to currently defined data views.
```

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/67885/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p00cato8pe46ein1bjcimkkx6hzd.htm

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/65287/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p00cato8pe46ein1bjcimkkx6hzd.htm

https://v8doc.sas.com/sashtml/proc/zsqldict.htm